# Multiple nodes in .scn model causing iMessage extension to crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am working with SceneKit in an iMessage extension and have run into a peculiar little beast of an issue. I am trying to render a custom scn model and rig nodes to a users facial expression using blend shape anchors. I am able to do this succesfully in the iOS app that this iMessage extension is born from without an issue. However, once placed into a MessageViewController the program exits with code 0 every time I try to run it.

I did a bit of digging and it seems "exited with code 0" is indicative of memory overload so I started playing around with my models nodes. I discovered that if I delete all nodes but one, I am able to animate that node with its corresponding blend shape. Any more than one node and it crashes.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? Or any proof that iMessage extensions are only granted a certain amount of processing power before they are killed off (another theory of mine)?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) we learn that

> **Memory limits for running app extensions are significantly lower than the memory limits imposed on a foreground app. On both platforms, the system may aggressively terminate extensions because users want to return to their main goal in the host app.** Some extensions may have lower memory limits than others: For example, widgets must be especially efficient because users are likely to have several widgets open at the same time.
>
> Your app extension doesn’t own the main run loop, so it’s crucial that you follow the established rules for good behavior in main run loops. For example, if your extension blocks the main run loop, it can create a bad user experience in another extension or app.
>
> **Keep in mind that the GPU is a shared resource in the system. App extensions do not get top priority for shared resources; for example, a Today widget that runs a graphics-intensive game might give users a bad experience. The system is likely to terminate such an extension because of memory pressure.** Functionality that makes heavy use of system resources is appropriate for an app, not an app extension.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to try to optimize your geometry in your DCC so you don't run into system resource constraints.